# Python fsolve() complains about shape. Why?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Having the function f(x,y,z), I need to solve the restriction f(x,y,z) = 0 and then plot it. I tried to find for each pair (y,z) the value x for which f(x,y,z) = 0:

```
from numpy import *
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def func(x,y,z):
    return x+y+z

y = linspace(0,1,100)
z = linspace(0,1,100)
x0 = zeros((y.size,z.size)) + 0.5 # the initial guess
yz = (y[:,newaxis],z[newaxis,:]) # the other parameters
x, info, iterations, message = fsolve(func,x0,yz)
contour(y,z,x)
```

Python (2.7.5) says "TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'func'."

But if I test it myself, it gives the same shape:

```
func(x0,y[:,newaxis],z[:,newaxis]).shape == x0.shape
```

returns True.

Why does fsolve() complain?

Comment: it's not the same function call. what if you test `func(x0,y[:,newaxis],z[:,newaxis]).shape == x0.shape`? Without seeing the `func` code, debugging this for you could be hard.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have just realized this and was about to change it in the question. I tried it and it also gives the same shape.

Comment: The function is a long piece of program, but the same behavior occurs with the one line function def func(x,y,z): return x+y+z; I don't think it's because of the function.

Comment: I've added the import statements. Please make sure your example runs as-is next time. It makes things that much easier for people trying to help

Comment: Seems like fsolve flattens the x array. if you print x.shape inside func you get (10000L,)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fsolve` expects the `x` argument and the return value of `func` to be a scalar or one-dimensional array.  You'll have to modify your code to work with flattened `x` values.  E.g.

```
def func(x, y, z):
    x = x.reshape(y.size, z.size)
    return (x + y + z).ravel()
```

and something like this for the call to `fsolve`:

```
sol, info, ier, mesg = fsolve(func, x0.ravel(), args=yz, full_output=True)
x = sol.reshape(y.size, z.size)
```

Comment: Yes, now fsolve() doesn't complain any more, but it takes ages to complete. For a 10 x 10 matrix it works, but for a mere 100 x 100 matrix it is still working after 10 minutes. Maybe fsolve() is not the best option for my problem. I will post another question about the general strategy in such cases. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: 100x100 matrix is 10000 variables, which is too much for fsolve. See [scipy.optimize tutorial on large problems](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#root-finding-for-large-problems).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a comparison to the `krylov` method advertized in the [scipy.optimize tutorial](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#root-finding-for-large-problems):

```
from numpy import linspace, zeros, newaxis
import time
from scipy.optimize import root

def func(x,y,z):
    x = x.reshape(y.size, z.size)
    f = x + y + z
    f = f.ravel()
    return f

n = 50
y = linspace(0,1,n)
z = linspace(0,1,n)
x0 = zeros((y.size,z.size)) + 0.5 # the initial guess
yz = (y[:,newaxis],z[newaxis,:]) # the other parameters

start = time.time()
sol1 = root(func, x0.ravel(), args=yz, method='hybr', tol=1e-7)  # same as fsolve
x1 = sol1.x.reshape(y.size, z.size)
print("(fsolve) time taken (sec): %g" % (time.time() - start,))
print("(fsolve) successful: %r (%s)" % (sol1.success, sol1.message))
print("(fsolve) max error: %g" % (abs(func(x1, *yz)).max(),))

start = time.time()
sol2 = root(func, x0.ravel(), args=yz, method='krylov', tol=1e-9)
x2 = sol2.x.reshape(y.size, z.size)
print("(krylov) time taken (sec): %g" % (time.time() - start,))
print("(krylov) successful: %r (%s)" % (sol2.success, sol2.message))
print("(krylov) max error: %g" % (abs(func(x2, *yz)).max(),))
```

Prints

```
(fsolve) time taken (sec): 26.9296
(fsolve) successful: False (The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the 
  improvement from the last ten iterations.)
(fsolve) max error: 1.52656e-16
(krylov) time taken (sec): 0.0173709
(krylov) successful: True (A solution was found at the specified tolerance.)
(krylov) max error: 1.11022e-16
```