# I/O shape mismatch when using scipy.optimize.fsolve on 2-dimensional anonymous function array variable

Tags: python, scipy

Here is the source code:

```
def lambdatest():
    F=lambda y: y-np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
    y0=np.array([[3,4],[8,7]])    
    Y=scipy.optimize.fsolve(F,y0)
    return Y
```

And the error I get is:

```
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument '<lambda>'.
```

I have looked around but can't seem to make sense of it.

Comment: I should have remembered this one before answering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21734602/python-fsolve-complains-about-shape-why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`F` (the `func` argument of [`fsolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html)) must return either a scalar or a one-dimensional array.  `fsolve` doesn't handle higher dimensional arrays.

What you can do is flatten the 2-d array to a 1-d array using the [`ravel()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html) method, and then reshape the solution returned by `fsolve` into a 2-d array:

```
def lambdatest():
    F = lambda y: y - np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]).ravel()
    y0 = np.array([[3,4],[8,7]])            
    Y = scipy.optimize.fsolve(F, y0.ravel()).reshape(y0.shape)
    return Y
```

Here's the result:

```
>>> lambdatest()
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  4.]])
```

Comment: Works wonderfully, Many Thanks. Sorry it was a duplicate problem I had searched around but didn't find that particular post.